# google mapsplace picker close immediately after launch

Tags: android, google-maps

when try to create android place picker inside onclick

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {

                Intent intent = builder.build(this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

place picker open and close immediately after second
i added to my manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

and connected with my console and still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This place picker is deprecated you need to use new one 
use this in your app level gradle 
 implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

```
 try {
                Places.initialize(Objects.requireNonNull(this), "YOUR_KEY");
                PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
                List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS,
                        Place.Field.ID,
                        Place.Field.PHONE_NUMBER,
                        Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
                Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                        AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, placeFields)
                        .build(this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In your activity result

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST:
                assert data != null;
                Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                String placeName = Objects.requireNonNull(place.getAddress()).toString();



        }
    }
```

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: but this method  for place search using Autocomplete not included Place Picker !!!

Comment: i used Autocomplete and worked but is there  any way to implement place picker like old way using new implementation ?

Comment: place picker is deprecated , from now you can only use autocomplete places sdk